# How to ensure machine reboot after the puppet run

Tags: puppet

is there a way how to ensure the reboot of the linux machine after puppet run?

Can take advantage of reboot or shutdown -r commands and to typical patern resurce - subscribe pattern but that doesn't ensure that exec shutdown resource will be synchronized as a last one.

Could someone please advice the best approach?

Comment: I answered [a very similar question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/611200/puppet-how-to-run-an-exec-only-if-puppet-has-made-changes) before.

Comment: I was thinking about creating stage e.g. post where would be this kind of activities which performs restarts etc.But not sure how this feature is available across puppet versions.

Comment: Is there any possibility to continue running puppet after system restart automatically?

Comment: Stages are available since 2.6.0 iirc. Your inquiry for a "resume" style behavior is a new question. All of these would be better suited to ServerFault, since this is more about Puppet's operational aspects than actual manifest code design.